# Centroid of a parabolic arc

Tags: definite-integrals, analytic-geometry, polar-coordinates, classical-mechanics, centroid

> Find the centroid $C=(\bar{x},\bar{y})$ of the parabolic arc $y=16-x^2$ over $[-4,4]$.

From symmetry, $$\bar{x}=0$$
To find $\bar{y}$, substitute $\tilde{y}=y$,  $dL=\sqrt{1+4x^2} dx$ in
$$\frac{\int_{-4}^{4} {\tilde{y} dL}}{\int_{-4}^{4} {dL}}=\frac{\int_{-4}^{4} {(16-x^2) \sqrt{1+4x^2} dx}}{\int_{-4}^{4} {\sqrt{1+4x^2} dx}}$$

This is in rectangular coordinates. Is it correct?
Also, how would I do this in polar coordinates?

Comment: Are you asking how to set up the integral in polar, or do you want the polar coordinates of the centroid, i.e. $(\bar r,\bar\theta)$?

Comment: Setting up the integral

Comment: This is correct. I get $\overline{y} \approx 8.272825$ with $L \approx 33.63727$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup in rectangular coordinates is correct.

To get the same integral in polar coordinates, let

$$\begin{cases}x(\theta) = r(\theta) \cos\theta \\ y(\theta) = r(\theta) \sin\theta\end{cases}$$

where $r(\theta)$ is the polar representation of the curve, which we can solve for upon replacing all the variables:

$$y = 16-x^2 \\
\implies r\sin\theta = 16 - r^2\cos^2\theta \\
\implies r = \frac{-\sin\theta \pm \sqrt{1+63\cos^2\theta}}{2\cos^2\theta}$$

Choose the solution with the positive square root, which traces out the [same parabola](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=polar+plot+%28-sin%28theta%29+%2B+sqrt%281%2B63*cos%5E2%28theta%29%29%29%2F%282*cos%5E2%28theta%29%29+from+0+to+pi) when $\theta\in[0,\pi]$,

$$r(\theta) = \frac{-\sin\theta + \sqrt{1+63\cos^2\theta}}{2\cos^2\theta}$$

By the chain rule, $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{dy}{d\theta}\cdot\dfrac{d\theta}{dx}$, so we can rewrite the line element as

$$\begin{align*}
dL &= \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} \, dx \\
&= \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\frac{dy}{d\theta}}{\frac{dx}{d\theta}}\right)^2} \, \frac{dx}{d\theta} \, d\theta \\
&= \sqrt{\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\cos\theta-r(\theta)\sin\theta\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\sin\theta+r(\theta)\cos\theta\right)^2} \, d\theta
\end{align*}$$

Plugging in $r(\theta)$ makes quite the mess, so I won't bother simplifying this any further.

The integrals for arc length and each moment are given by

$$\begin{align*}
L &= \int_0^\pi dL \\
L_r &= \int_0^\pi \left(16-\left(r(\theta)\cos\theta\right)^2\right) \, dL \\
L_\theta &= \int_0^\pi \theta \, dL
\end{align*}$$

so that the arc length is $L\approx33.637$, and the polar centroid of the curve is the point

$$\left(\bar r,\bar\theta\right)=\left(\frac{L_r}L,\frac{L_\theta}L\right)\approx\left(8.273,1.571\right)=\left(\ldots,\dfrac\pi2\right)$$

The $r$-coordinate is the same as the $y$-coordinate of the rectangular centroid so one can determine its value exactly if desired.